# iOS Bluetooth background mode change in production build

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-peripheral

I have already released my app in AppStore with Bluetooth always enabled in background mode. Now the requirement has changed and now I am removing Bluetooth from the background mode.

With this updated change, when I release the app in TestFlight, the app crashes every time the user opens it. The only way is to uninstall and then install the app. How can I solve this in production build?

Before: [in production build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIw6n.png)

After: [Want to release this without app crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neZCs.png)

Comment: Show some relevant code snippets to make it easier for others to see where the source of the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by code, related to Bluetooth settings. However, I have added the screenshot of the configuration. @Buzz